# ng-repeat in controller to change DOM with js

Tags: angularjs

I have JSON which stores a list of options. I want to manipulate the DOM with jQuery in controller. For example, I have a `<div id="div"></div>` in html and I want to do

```
$scope.options = "options come from JSON";
$('#div').append("<select ng-model='model'><option ng-repeat='opt in options'>{{opt.value}}</option></select>")
```

in controller. When I open the html page `<select></select>`  tag is coming but options are empty. My question is that how can I loop options with ng-repeat  in controller and send to html page? Thank you.

Comment: If you do DOM manipulations when using Angular, you **really** pass by Angular strength...

Comment: why are you trying to do this in this manner?  In general, it should set off flags in your head if you ever are finding a need to manually adjust the DOM with Angular.  Also, Angular will have no way of knowing that JQuery inserted something that it should evaluate and compile.

Comment: there *are* ways to have angular compile the information so that it can be inserted, but providing that information here would only promote a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. My actually purpose is that I have a database which holds html elements parameters like `{"name":"input","type":"number"},{"name":"input","type":"button"}`... and so on. I got these JSON format and I have to generate them on html page. Assume that we don't know how many element requires and which elements we have. Any suggestions????

Comment: so are you doing something similar to Formly?  http://angular-formly.com/#/

Comment: My purpose is generate all form  elements dynamically according to JSON. Different type of JSON element requires different form. For example if login form infos come from JSON, must generate login form in view or if contact form infos come from JSON, must generate contact form in view. Is angular-formly provides that? or another way?

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer using Angular [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="opt.value for opt in options"></select>
```

---

As a side note (despite the fact that this code can work), you should avoid doing DOM manipulations on an AngularJS app. It is not JQuery, and it is not the *Angular way* to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do DOM manipulation in such a simple example - in general, you should save it for directives. Just write this in your HTML straight up:

```
<div id="div">
  <select ng-model='model'>
    <option ng-repeat='opt in options'>{{opt.value}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Could do something like this

```
//View
<select ng-if="options">
    <option ng-repeat="opt in options">{{opt.value}}</option>
</select>

//Controller
$scope.options = <The JSON object>;
```